# Best Way To Learn Mobile App Programming?

Tags: mobile

I was reading about a site called SkyBuilder.net where you can build Android and iPhone Apps.  I'm afraid it is a bit too basic for me.  Can someone off me the best place to really learn how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stanford has a great course on iPhone development.  You can view the lecture notes and assignments [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2011-fall) and/or watch the lectures [here](http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255?mt=10). Their [main iTunes U page](http://itunes.stanford.edu/) is a guide/portal to getting everything setup to watch the lectures.

I highly recommend taking advantage of courses that the top Computer Science schools put online for everyone to view.  It doesn't cost you any money and you gain a lot of knowledge in the process.

Comment: Try out this [this](http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2010/10/12/android-dev-tutorial-now-available-on-the-gvsu-itunes-u-portal/)